# Is it efficient to have 2 SQL tables with the same structure?

Tags: sql

In inventory / production systems I usually implement a table structure similar to the following description...

```
--- Raw Item ---
id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
ideal INT(10) UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

And another table with the same fields for the processed items...

Next tables for clients and providers with similar structures.

Then tables for income orders and outcome orders with similar structures.

And finally, a table which stablishes relationships between a certain processed item and the types of raw items (With quantities) required to produce a batch...

It performs well... But I wonder if it would be better to merge the similar tables and adding a field such as 'type', would like some advice please.

Comment: It is probably better to have one table with flags -- such as whether an item has been processed or not.

Comment: There's also an advantage to using a single table if you are going to UNION the tables in a query somewhere. With a single table you can just use a more inclusive WHERE clause instead of UNION.

Answer (score 4):

In my mind adding an artificial type to combine similar data is not 3NF. Go with separate tables unless you need the data in the same table.

A client and a provider have similar fields but they are two different things.

If an order migrates from PO to Processed then it is the same thing and it would be appropriate to have a status flag.   If you are moving data from one table to the other then combine with a flag is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question and as many SQL good questions the answer is "it depends".

IMHO it's ok to create similar (internal structured tables) for different artifacts (with similar properties).
See you can get:

```
Owner
Id, Name

Pet
Id, Name
```

Tables with same columns but different **meaning**.
Sure you can got Items and RawItens in the same table and just a Flag column to differentiate between both. You can even use a self referencing FK to relate Items with RamItems but how that can affect performance?

Well as your table grows engine will need more time (resources, mem, cpu) to retrieve rows/data. If you double the rows... for most DBMS doubling tables ill affect performance a lot less doubling a table rows.

Also it affects evolutive maintenance. If now you need to add one column for your RawItems but not for your Items you can become wasting space.

"Merging" similar tables can increase dificult to understand your schema, not simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine this would depend slightly on your database schema you choose. See this link for a little more information; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html

Each one would offer you various degrees of performance improvements and lack of features in certain areas. I guess the real question is do you want to have to deal with multiple tables, or would it be easier to deal with a single table?

A simple solution to this would be to add something simple like a status to the table. Then just change your queries to run a check against the status. Very simple, and space efficient way to save both tables into one.

```
--- Raw Item ---
id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
ideal INT(10) UNSIGNED,
status VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)

SELECT * from items WHERE status="PROCESSED";
```

Personally I would prefer this approach. It leaves you with only a single table of inventory, as opposed to having multiple tables cluttering up the database schema. Not to mention if it ever expands further (say, you have new, processed, and archived).

Answer (score 1):

How are you going to use the data over time? If you need to combine all these tables together for reporting, one table is likely preferable with partitioning if it is very large. If you need to move the records from one table to the other as it moves throguh a process, it is easier to check on the status of a process if it is all in one table.

Also, if the things are very different entities, they may have differnt related tables and then combining them just muddies the waters, makes the datbase more difficult to understand,  and reduces the effectiveness of your PK/FK relationships. In this case, separate tables makes the most sense. It also makes the most sense if you think the data will diverge over time as currently planned features are added.

Take for instance a customer and a Sales rep. They might have many of the same fields but what they are related to will be very differnt and you would not want a customer to be able to be put into the child table for a rep. So now you have to enfore the relationships with more than an FK. Further if you have enough child tables, it makes deleting records to be difficult.  The db has to check all the tables even if only half of them might apply to a particular record.

In one database I have seen, the orginal designer combined two things that were dissimlar but had the same fields at the parent level and ended up with well over 100 FKs on that table. It was a nightmare to delete from that table and never fast. And there were occasional data integrity problems where one type of record ended up in the wrong child tables.